# Changing port on XAMPP

Tags: macos, xampp

I just install XAMPP on my mac and I'm unable to Run Apache Web server. It does not let me since I'm already running a different server. How can I stop the current one or how can I use a different port.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you aren't in the correct file.Try

`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf`

instead of

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

Find and open `httpd.conf` in **XAMPP apache configuration directory**, find the line that says `Listen 80`, change that to port you wish e.g: 8000 so that line becomes `Listen 8000`. Then save the file and restart apache from xampp

To access type `http://localhost:8000` on your browser address bar, and open

Comment: I open httpd.conf but I don't see line: Listen 80

Comment: This is what I have in that file:Alias /bitnami/ "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: Is there no line that says `Listen` at all? Maybe it's `Listen 1234` or something, and **note that** hashtag (#) mark before Listen is a comment so you may want to remove it

Comment: I don't have "Listen.." in httpd.conf at all.